# strongswan (IPSec) Site to Site VPN подключение через windows (psk)

Tags: linux, windows, сеть, безопасность, vpn

> Всем привет, есть установленный site to site vpn (strongswan ipsec) на
>   сервере в туннельном режиме.

При попытке подключения к vpn на компьютере с `Linux`

Подключаюсь при помощи команды `ipsec up tunnel` , соединение устанавливается, и все работает отлично, пишет что `tunnel established`.

Вопрос в том, как подключиться на компьютере с `Windows 10`?
Пытаюсь подключиться с помощью стандартного метода vpn подключения, через

```
Network -> Connect to remote Desktop -> VPN
```

Настраиваю, но при подключении, смотрю в логи сервера и вижу там ошибку

```
NO Matching CHILD_SA config found
```

Гуглю, все еще не могу найти решение проблемы, не подскажите люди добрые ?

вот конфигурационный файл ipsec.conf на сервере

```
conn vpnserver
  type=tunnel
  authby=secret
  pfs=no
  rekey=no
  keyingtries=1

  left=%any
  leftsubnet=x.x.x.x/x
  leftprotoport=udp/l2tp

  right=%any
  rightsubnet=y.y.y.y/y
  rightprotoport=udp/l2tp

  keylife=1h
  ikelifetime=1h
  keyexchange=ikev1
  ike=null
  esp=null

  auto=add
```